# GLTF model has transparent face

Tags: graphics, 3d, gltf, ifc-open-shell

I created a gltf file from a third-party software (ifcOpenshell) and my problem is that one side of my model has a solid color while the other side of my model is transparent when viewed on [gltfviewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/)

Here is the front side of my model:

[image: front]

And here is the back of the model:

[image]

As you can see, it's transparent.

Here is what the mesh looks like:

[image: mesh]

And well as a closeup of the normals:

[image: normals]

I can't figure out what the issue is. I would appreciate any insights. Thank you.

Here is a link to the glb [file](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/xtcqvdqgn8uhm669cbxkk/roof_enf.glb?rlkey=2h7x83mbe7l3xi0cgkc2j2hn8&dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Materials in glTF have a `doubleSided` parameter, and when disabled, a surface is visible only from the front. This file contains only single-sided materials. For a quick test to compare with `doubleSided=true`, drag the model into https://gltf.report/ and then paste and run the script below in the scripting tab:

```js
for (const material of document.getRoot().listMaterials()) {
    material.setDoubleSided(true);
}
```

I'm unsure whether ifcOpenshell has the ability to change the `doubleSided` parameter before export.

One of the thin edges on the side of the mesh is missing entirely, so that won't be fixed by this material setting.